In Kerberos, is the "Authentication Server" the only "Trusted Third Party"? Or is "Ticket Granting Server" also a "Trusted Third Party"?
I know that AS (Authentication Server) is a TTP (Trusted Third Party) because it generates keys for two entities (for the client and the TGS).
But what about TGS (Ticket Granting Server)? It also generates keys for two entities (generates for client and server). So is it also TGS a TTP?

What if it is not TTP? Can you use any service at all?

Cross posted with security.se and got answer there.

I’m voting to close this question because also asked in security.se and got an answer, there.
